# Flattening a nested ORC file with Spark - Performance issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nested, orc

We are facing a severe performance issue when reading a nested ORC file.

This is our ORC schema:

```
|-- uploader: string (nullable = true)
|-- email: string (nullable = true)
|-- data: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true) 
|    |    |-- startTime: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- endTime: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- val1: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- val2: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- val3: integer (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- val4: integer (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- val5: integer (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- val6: integer (nullable = true)
```

The ‘data’ array could potentially contain 75K objects.

In our spark application, we flatten this ORC, as you can see below:

```
val dataFrame = spark.read.orc(files: _*)
val withData = dataFrame.withColumn("data", explode(dataFrame.col("data")))
val withUploader = withData.select($"uploader", $"data")
val allData = withUploader
  .withColumn("val_1", $"data.val1")
  .withColumn("val_2", $"data.val2")
  .withColumn("val_3", $"data.val3")
  .withColumn("val_4", $"data.val4")
  .withColumn("val_5", $"data.val5")
  .withColumn("val_6", $"data.val6")
  .withColumn("utc_start_time", timestampUdf($"data.startTime"))
  .withColumn("utc_end_time", timestampUdf($"data.endTime"))

allData.drop("data")
```

The flattening process seems to be a very heavy operation: 
Reading a 2MB ORC file with 20 records, each of which contains a data array with 75K objects, results in hours of processing time. Reading the file and collecting it without flattening it, takes 22 seconds.

Is there a way to make spark process the data faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps someone, I found that flattening the data using flatmap is much faster than doing it with explode:

```
dataFrame.as[InputFormat].flatMap(r => r.data.map(v => OutputFormat(v, r.tenant)))
```

The improvement in performance was dramatic.

Processing a file with 20 records, each containing an array with 250K rows- with the explode implementation it took 8 hours, with the flatmap implementation- 7 minutes (!)

Answer (score 2):

I'd try to avoid large `explodes` completely. With 75K elements in the array:

- You create 75K `Row` objects per `Row`. This is a huge allocation effort.
- You duplicate `uploaded` and `email` 75K times. In short term it will reference the same data, but once data is serialized and deserialized with internal format, they'll like point to different objects effectively multiplying memory requirements.

Depending on the transformations you want to apply it might be the case where using UDF to process arrays as whole, will be much more efficient.